# Finding the length of a ray within a cube

Tags: algorithm, math, shader

I have a ray, going outwards from a camera, I need to find the length of the ray inside the cube. Note that the camera could be inside the cube, in which case it should return the distance to the edge of the cube.

It's for a shader, so it should be relatively small and involve a minimum of branching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To intersect a ray with a convex polyhedron, intersect the ray with the planes containing each face.

Suppose the ray starts at **q** and has direction **r**. Then any point on the ray can be represented as **q** + *t* **r** for a scalar parameter *t*. Now suppose we want to intersect this ray with the plane given by the equation *p* · **n** = *k* (where **n** is an outward-pointing unit normal to the face). The ray intersects the plane when

> (**q** + *t* **r**) · **n** = *k*

That is, when

> **q** · **n** + *t* **r** · **n** = *k*

and so

> *t* = (*k* − **q** · **n**) / **r** · **n**

The ray enters the face when **r** · **n** is negative and exits when **r** · **n** is positive. When **r** · **n** is zero, the ray is parallel to the face. You need to check for this case to avoid division by zero; and in this case, if **q** · **n** > *k*, the ray misses the polyhedron completely.

So find *t* for all the faces of your polyhedron and let *t*<sub>in</sub> be the maximum *t* for the the points where the ray enters a face, and *t*<sub>out</sub> be the minimum *t* for the points where the ray exits a face. Then the length of the ray within the polyhedron is

> max(max(*t*<sub>out</sub>, 0) − max(*t*<sub>in</sub>, 0), 0) / |**r**|

If **r** is a unit vector you can avoid the division here. The two inner max(*t*, 0) are necessary to handle the case where the camera is inside the cube or the cube is behind the camera. The outer max(..., 0) is there to handle the case where the ray misses the cube entirely (in which case *t*<sub>in</sub> will be greater than *t*<sub>out</sub>).

I'm afraid I have no idea how to represent this computation in your shader language, let alone how to do so branchlessly.

Comment: Thanks! The translating into openGL's shader language will be no problem. Since my cube is axis alingned I can simplify your already compact equations more! This will work great.

Comment: what is k here?  It looks like it is supposed to be the planar offset, *p0*, but if that's the case why isn't it stated?

Comment: @opa: You are right that |k| is the perpendicular distance of the plane from the origin, but I assumed that the OP was familiar with the equation of a plane and so didn't need me to remind them of this detail.

Comment: the equation of a plane is defined according to wikipedia as `(p-p0)*n = 0`.  This is also the only definition of a plane I've seen before this.  To one familiar with that definition this one looks foreign.

Comment: @opa: You just have to expand the parentheses: if (p − p₀)·n = 0 then p·n = p₀·n = *k*.

Answer (score 2):

It would be fine if you told us what exactly you need this for. You can do it easily by rendering the cube and then reading the z-buffer which contains distances from camera to every visible point of the cube. The point in the middle is where the camera is looking.

Otherwise you will need to perform a [ray-plane intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection) for each of the planes of the cube, check that the intersection is within the range of the cube and also check that it is not behind the camera. You can get either of these three cases:

1. No intersection
2. One intersection - you are inside the cube, calculate the distance between the intersection and camera position
3. Two intersections - you are outside the cube, calculate the distance between the two intersections
4. Infinitely many intersections - the view vector is a tangent to the cube, just throw away the tangent plane intersections and take only two intersections to the two adjacent planes

You will need to send the cube information to the shader unit. The computation will be the same for all shaders so I don't see a point in putting it in a shader - it would be better to compute this once on the CPU. Also, it involves branching (I have no idea how to avoid it).

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember to explain more about what I'm doing in the future. I'm simulating a cube shaped atmosphere, and I need to know how much of the atmosphere we are looking through to determine the color. I will consider using the z-buffer, since I could render realistic fog for the landscape too. Also the computation is done per vertex.

Comment: Why using cube? Sphere (or hemisphere) is definitely more suitable for an atmosphere. Also the intersection calculations are significantly easier.

Comment: Because our world is a giant cube, a cube world deserves no less than a cube atmosphere.